# Getting error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift

Error is produced at UISegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex

I've tried with title property, instead of the switch, but it didn't help, the same error appeared.

When I comment the whole function and try to print the numberOfColumnsSelector.selectedSegmentIndex it doesn't crash and prints the right answer.

The Console outputs: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

I commented below which line is causing that error:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //Declaring variables
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfColumnsSelector: UISegmentedControl!        
    @IBOutlet weak var populatedPlacesSelector: UITextField!

    var numberOfColumns: Int = 0
    var populatedPlaces: [Int] = []

    // This makes those previously declared variables accessible
    func makeVariablesAccessible () -> ( size: Int, popPlacesArray: [Int] ) {
        // THE LINE BELOW IS THE PROBLEMATIC ONE
        switch numberOfColumnsSelector.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            numberOfColumns = 2
        case 1:
            numberOfColumns = 3
        case 2:
            numberOfColumns = 4
        case 3:
            numberOfColumns = 5
        case 4:
            numberOfColumns = 6
        case 6:
            numberOfColumns = 7
        case 8:
            numberOfColumns = 8
        default:
            numberOfColumns = 2
        }

        if populatedPlacesSelector.text != "" {
            var counter = 0
            var popPlaceString = ""
            for c in populatedPlacesSelector.text!.characters {
                if c == "." {
                    populatedPlaces.append(Int(popPlaceString)!)
                    print(populatedPlaces)
                    print(popPlaceString)
                    popPlaceString = ""
                    counter++
                }
                else {
                    popPlaceString.append(c)
                }
            }
        }
        return ( numberOfColumns, populatedPlaces )
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that `numberOfColumnsSelector` is not nil? Maybe your outlet is not hooked up properly.

Comment: Yes, so the program is telling me it's nil (at least that's what I think), but the connections are done properly (I just rechecked it).

Comment: When does this code run? It needs to be at least in viewDidLoad. Any earlier, like in the initializer, the outlets won't be set yet.

Comment: @Michael, the code runs when I press a button in the UI, after the view loaded

Comment: If `numberOfColumnsSelector` is nil, then the outlet is not configured correctly. Right-click the control in the UI and you will see what outlet(s) are configured, if any.

Comment: @Michael the connection is done properly, I just deleted the old segmented control and built a new one, the same thing happened. When I set up something similar in a different file, it works.

Comment: In that case, have you tried restarting XCode and doing a Clean before Build?

Comment: @Michael Didn't work, by the way when I comment the whole function and try to print the numberOfColumnsSelector.selectedSegmentIndex it doesn't crash and prints the right answer.

Comment: Try to create variable and store value there, then switch

Comment: @user3237732 Same Problem...

Comment: @PKLJ now when you are trying to store value?

Comment: @user3237732 I've tried both in and out of the makeVariablesAccessible function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was that I was asking for the values on another ViewController, making them unaccessible, after I fixed that, it worked, thanks anyways to all of those who helped me out.